# How to get this inequality using induction (analysis)

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Consider the following functions $\theta:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $\Theta:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, sucha that:
$$
\theta(x) :=
\begin{cases}
1-|x|  & \text{if $|x|\le1$} \\
0 & \text{if $1\le|x|$}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

$$\Theta(\bar x)=\Theta(x_1,\dots,x_n):=\theta (x_1)\dots\theta(x_n)$$

> Prove by induction on $n$, that: $|\Theta(x)-\Theta(y)|\le n\|x-y\|_{\infty}$

So for the base, I took $n=1$, let $x,y\in\Bbb R$, then $|\Theta(x)-\Theta(y)|=|\theta(x)-\theta (y)|$, so we get the following cases:

- if $|x,y|\le1$ then $|\theta(x)-\theta (y)|=|1-|x|-1+|y||=||y|-|x||\le|x-y|=\|x-y\|_{\infty}$
- if $|x|\le1,1\le|y|$ then $|\theta(x)-\theta (y)|=|1-|x|-0|=|1-|x||\le|1-x|\le|y-x|=|x-y|=\|x-y\|_{\infty}$
- if $|y|\le1,1\le|x|$ then is just like the case before.
- if $1\le|x,y|$ then $|0-0|=0\le \|x-y\|_{\infty}$

So $|\Theta(x)-\Theta(y)|\le \|x-y\|_{\infty}$ for $n=1$

The next step would be the inductive hypothesis, however I wanted to try for $n=2$ to see what happens. Let $(x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2)\in\Bbb R^2$, so $|\Theta(x)-\Theta(y)|=|\theta(x_1)\theta(x_2)-\theta (y_1)\theta (y_2)|$, if $\theta$ isn't $0$ for any $x_i,y_i$, then:
$$\begin{align}
|\theta(x_1)\theta(x_2)-\theta (y_1)\theta (y_2)|&=|(1-|x_1|)(1-|x_2|)-(1-|y_1|)(1-|y_2|)|\\
& = |1-|x_1|-|x_2|+|x_1||x_2|-1+|y_1|+|y_2|-|y_1||y_2||\\
& = ||x_1|-|y_1|+|x_2|-|y_2| +|y_1y_2|-|x_1x_2||\\
& \le ||x_1|-|y_1||+||x_2|-|y_2||+||y_1y_2|-|x_1x_2||\\
& \le \sup_{i=1,2} |x_i-y_i|+\sup_{i=1,2} |x_i-y_i|+|y_1y_2-x_1x_2|\\
& =2\|x-y\|_{\infty}+|y_1y_2-x_1x_2|
\end{align}$$
clearly $0\le|y_1y_2-x_1x_2|$, so what am I doing wrong? How can I get the inequality?

 I think proving for $n=2$ is important, because I feel that the inductive step looks pretty much like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I thought the symbol $*$ meant something else but it is just a product, fine!

First observe that $|\theta(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and hence $|\theta (x_1)\theta (x_2) \cdots \theta(x_n)|\leq 1 $ for all $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n\in \mathbb{R}$.

Then you showed that for $n=1$,
$$|\Theta (x) - \Theta (y) | = |\theta(x_1)-\theta(y_1)|= ||\leq \|x_1-y_1\|_{\infty}.$$

Suppose it holds for any other values $k\neq n$ where $n\geq 0$ fixed. Let ussee that it also holds for $k=n+1$. Just Write
\begin{align*}
|\Theta (x) &- \Theta (y)|=\\
&=|\theta(x_{n+1})\left( \theta(x_1)\cdots \theta(x_n)-\theta(y_1)\cdots \theta(y_n)\right) + \theta(y_1)\cdots \theta(y_n)\left(\theta(x_{n+1})-\theta(y_{n+1}) \right)|\\
&\leq |\theta(x_{n+1})||\theta(x_1)\cdots \theta(x_n)-\theta(y_1)\cdots \theta(y_n)|\\
&+ |\theta(y_1)\cdots \theta(y_n)||\theta(x_{n+1})-\theta(y_{n+1})|\\
&\leq n\|x-y\|_{\infty}\\
&+ \|x-y\|_{\infty}\\
&= (n+1)\|x-y\|_{\infty}
\end{align*}
where in the last step we use $|\theta (x_{n+1})|\leq 1$ and the inductive hypothesis and that $ |\theta(y_1)\cdots \theta(y_n)|\leq 1$ and that $)|\theta(x_{n+1})-\theta(y_{n+1})|$ since we know it holds for $n=1$.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the $*$, I'll edit that. I didn't realized how important $|\theta(x)|\le 1$ was, thank you for your answer. However, just for curiosity, in my proof for $n=2$, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I do not see anything "wrong" but I think Your very first estimate was too rough. If you want to really fix it, try to write $x_1x_2-y_1y_2 = (x_1-y_1)x_2+(x_2-y_2)y_1$ and Group all terms like $|x_i-y_i|$ then take supremum. I did not try but I Guess this should fix the rough estimate you got.